# I want to update value of a particular xml tag using python code?

Tags: python, xml

```
My xml file looks like below :-


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Messages xmlns="URL/sampleMessages-v1">
    <Header>
        <TransactionId>0</TransactionId>
        <RequestNo>41194812</RequestNo>
        <VNo>6789</VNo>
        <Source></Source>
    </Header>
...
...

</Messages>
```

I want to read it and change   the RequestNo value

```
 <RequestNo>41194812</RequestNo> to 
        <RequestNo>41194000</RequestNo>

I am using ElementTree module  currently. I am using windows machine currently.
```

I want to update the value in the same file.

Ihave tried below code :-

```
for elem in root:
    for subelem in elem:
      #print (subelem.tag)
        if 'RequestNo' in subelem.tag :
            #print (subelem.text)
            subelem.text="41194813"
```

But i am not able to see the change or i dont know currently how to write this new value subelem.text="41194813" in existing xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop does the job: it did replace the text correctly. The change is in your `root` variable. You can verify that by adding the following line right after the for loop:

```
ElementTree.dump(root)
```

Now that you have the XML updated, you will need to write that into a file:

```
tree.write('newfile.xml')
```

Where `tree` is the result of `ElementTree.parse()`. So, to put everything together:

```
tree = ElementTree.parse('messages.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root:
    for subelem in elem:
        if 'RequestNo' in subelem.tag:
            subelem.text = '41194813'
            break
tree.write('messages-new.xml')
```

## Dealing with Namespaces

Your XML document contains namespaces, so if you plan to search for a tag, you need to include the namespaces in the tag names. Here is an alternative solution which deals with namespaces:

```
tree = ElementTree.parse('messages.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

namespaces = {'xxx': 'URL/sampleMessages-v1'}
node = root.find('xxx:Header/xxx:RequestNo', namespaces)
if node is not None:
    node.text = '41194813'

tree.write('messages-new.xml')
```

In the above example, I just gave your namespace the name 'xxx', it can be anything 'foo', 'bar', ... but should be used as prefix in the call to `root.find()`.

## Removing "ns0" from Output File

In order to remove "ns0" from output file, you need to register the namespace before writing:

```
ElementTree.register_namespace('', 'URL/sampleMessages-v1')
tree.write('messages-new.xml')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,it works.  But now in output.xml i get ns0   <ns0:RequestNo>41194813</ns0:RequestNo>   How to remove this ns0?